# GitPython: Determine files that were deleted in a specific commit

Tags: python, git, python-2.7, gitpython

Using gitpython, I am trying to get a list of changed paths; that is, of all the added, changed and deleted files.

I can retrieve the changed and added files from the commit:

- checkout commit 'X'
- traverse repo.tree() and collect all the blobs' abspath

If a file was deleted in a specific commit, it will not show up in the tree anymore. How can I get the names of all the deleted files?

Comment: Do you still want to do this? If so I've found a way.

Comment: @RobKwasowski Please make it an answer!

Comment: Sorry, I've realised what you're actually asking for. You want to know which files were deleted in a specific commit. I've only been investigating getting a list of deleted files when you do a new commit. So at the moment I still don't know how to do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the commit's parents and compare the contents of the two (or more, depending on the number of parents) trees.

Comment: Ok, I can do this via some set operations, but it seems overkill. It's probably easier to parse the output of git-log...Isn't there a built-in way?